# Abbreviation for jinmeiyō?

Tags: kanji, names, terminology, abbreviations

Is there an abbreviation for 人名用漢字, i.e. character set for names?

I'm looking for anything shorter, really; It can be English or Japanese, as long as it's widely recognised. For example like `Tel` for `telephone number` or like `男` for `男性`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 新漢和大辞典 uses the following shorthand:

- 〔人名〕 *jinmeiyō kanji*
- 〔常４〕 *jōyō kanji*, grade 4

Depending on the context, 人名 or 人名用 could work as "abbreviation" for indicating that a particular *kanji* belongs to the set of *jinmeiyō kanji*.